# Wordpress: Highlight active menu item

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on this [website](http://ziegler-p.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/)  and i am trying to highlight with a `border-bottom` the active menu link. As you can see is a one scroll website but i can't highlight it via CSS. I want to highlight the MÖGLICHKEITEN - GALERIE - KONTAKT links when they are active.
I tried this:

CSS:

```
#dslc-module-84 .dslc-navigation .menu > li > a:active { border-bottom: 1px solid #3da22b !important; }
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

[KONTAKT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCh7H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `parent child` selector CSS to achieve what you are looking for.

**For instance,**

```
.menu li.menu-item a._mPS2id-h.mPS2id-clicked.mPS2id-highlight{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3da22b !important; 
}
```

You need to target the main parent menu class which is `.menu` in your case and go on to select its child till you reach `li` with the selected menu. Once you do, target it's child `a` to achieve what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works only for the first link AREAL not for the others :/

Comment: I believe you need to recheck what you have tried, as I did a test and works fine here

Comment: Yeah now works, but not for the last link KONTAKT. How come?

Comment: It works on KONTAKT too. Check again and also clear your cache.

Comment: Try `.menu li.menu-item a._mPS2id-h.mPS2id-clicked`

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress provides classes for the current menu item (i.e: `.current-menu-item`).

You should use these selectors to declare your style rule for the given menu item.

**Examples:**

```
.menu li[class*="current"] {...}

.menu .current-menu-item {...}
```

**More specific to your case:**

```
.menu li a[class*="-highlight"],.menu li a[class*="-clicked"] {...}
```

Regarding the `:active` [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-classes) you initially tried to use:

> The :active CSS pseudo-class matches **when an element is being
>   activated by the user**. It allows the page to give a feedback that the
>   activation has been detected by the browser. When interacting with a
>   mouse, *this is typically the time between the user presses the mouse
>   button and releases it*. The :active pseudo-class is also typically
>   matched when using the keyboard tab key. It is frequently used on 
>   and  HTML elements, but may not be limited to just those.

(Source: active - CSS | MDN)

**Learn more:** [:active - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
#dslc-module-84 .dslc-navigation .menu > li.current-menu-item > a {
 color:#eee;
}
```